# 'android.app.Notification$Builder' Class not found

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-cloud-messaging

## Background

I'm working to make my app supporting 2.3.3 version (Api level 10), but i got the below error.

## Log

```
Could not find class 'android.app.Notification$Builder', referenced from method    
com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil.showErrorNotification
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Notification.Builder` was added in API level 11. For earlier versions, `NotificationCompat.Builder` should be used instead.

Since the error comes from Google Play Services, use `google_play_services_froyo` instead of `google_play_services` for pre-11 targets.